# Ember - dynamically pass array of dependent keys to computed property

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I would like to create a component that takes a list of property names and then dynamically builds a computed property which has each value from the list as a dependent key.

```html
{{buttons-list-component
  title="Status"
  propertyNames="active, expired, pending"
  toggleProperty="toggleProperty"
  active=active
  expired=expired
  pending=pending
}}
```

For the above example, I would like to to take the string passed as `propertyNames`, split it into an array and then have the `optionsObject` computed property watch each value in the array as if it was passed explicitly.

```js
propertiesArray: function() {
  return this.get('propertyNames').split(", ");
}.property('propertyNames'),
```

When the property `active` is updated, the code below will not run, because the `propertyNames` has not been updated, and therefore `propertiesArray` has not changed.

```js
optionsObject: function() {
  console.log("foo") // Does not run.
}.property('propertiesArray.@each'),
```

Is there a way to build the computed property, so that it would work in the same way as the code below, but without explicitly passing the string value of each property that `optionsObject` is dependant on?

```js
optionsObject: function() {
  console.log("bar") // Does run.
}.property('active', 'expired', 'pending''),
```

Comment: Am I right, that you want your popertyNames elements refer to objects? So that you would have access to a active expired an pending object?

Comment: Yes. So how can I convert them from a string to an array of Ember objects, and then make a computed function that will update when they update.

Answer (score 1):

Your propertyNames is being passed a constant string `propertyNames="active, expired, pending"` -- so to update propertyNames when active changes, pass a computed property to propertyNames which is calculated based on the three properties.

```js
propertyString: function() {
  return `${active} ${active} ${active}`
}.property('active', 'expired', 'pending'),
```

so now when propertyString updates, your propertyNames will update, and that will trigger propertiesArray.

One more thing to note here, you need to observe propertiesArray.[] not @each -- @each is used when observing a child property.

Also, you should use the new computed property format - https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/object-model/computed-properties/#toc-toggle explains the two points I mention well